# Colored Squares HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is the current index (HTML and JavaScript):

```js
var maxZ = 1000;
window.onload = function() {

  var add = document.getElementById("add");
  add.onclick = addSquare;

  var colors = document.getElementById("colors");
  colors.onclick = changeColors;

  var squareCount = parseInt(Math.random() * 21) + 30;
  for (var i = 0; i < squareCount; i++) {
    addSquare();
  }
}
//Generates color
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = "0123456789abcdef";
  var result = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    result += letters.charAt(parseInt(Math.random() * letters.length));
  }
  return result;
}

function addSquare() {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  var squareArea = document.getElementById("squareArea");
  square.className = "square";
  square.style.left = parseInt(Math.random() * 650) + "px";
  square.style.top = parseInt(Math.random() * 250) + "px";
  square.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  square.onclick = squareClick;
  squareArea.appendChild(square);
}

function changeColors() {
  var squares = document.querySelectorAll("#squareArea div");
  for (i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  }
}

function squareClick() {
  var oldZ = parseInt(this.style.zIndex);
  if (oldZ == maxZ) {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  } else {
    maxZ++;
    this.style.zIndex = maxZ;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Colored Squares</title>
  <script src="Squares.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="Squares.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="squareArea"></div>
  <div>
    <button id="add">Add Square</button>
    <button id="colors">Change Color</button>
  </div>
  <p>Click a square to move it to the front.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the goal:

Edit Colored squares to add the following functionality.

- Users will be able to click a square and drag it to any position on the screen. - When the user lets go of the click it will stay in that position.
- In order to accomplish this you will need to add Prototype and Scriptaculous to the scripts loaded in the html and use their functionality.
- You will also need to create 3 functions in the JavaScript file:

  1. function `squareMouseMove(event)`
  2. function `squareMouseDown(event)`
  3. function `squareMouseUp(event)`
  4. Add appropriate global variables
  5. Change the creation of the squares to added observers for the mouse events that execute the functions.

Comment: Actually try to do your homework, then post a question when you get stuck.  No one will try to read this and do it for you.

Comment: I did. This is where I'm stuck. I did the Index and the current Javascript. I need help trying to add those functions to the Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to SO Mike, in future please try and take more time with the format of your question - if you cannot be bothered to format and proof read your question, why whould we take the time to answer it?

Comment: I'm sorry I was trying to figure out how to do that. I'm not too good with this.

Comment: You missed to ask a question and post what you have done so far. Please [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it. Please clarify your specific problem. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have the program so that I can click squares and either add new ones or change the color. However, I need to click and drag them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have with your code is that the squares are empty, so they collapse to nothing and you will not see them. Add a width and height to them so you can see them.

Another issue is that you're specifying the `left` and `right`, but these properties will have no effect unless you make them absolutely positioned.

Here is your code working with the `width`, `height`, and `position` properties added:

```js
var maxZ = 1000;
window.onload = function() {

  var add = document.getElementById("add");
  add.onclick = addSquare;

  var colors = document.getElementById("colors");
  colors.onclick = changeColors;

  var squareCount = parseInt(Math.random() * 21) + 30;
  for (var i = 0; i < squareCount; i++) {
    addSquare();
  }
}
//Generates color
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = "0123456789abcdef";
  var result = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    result += letters.charAt(parseInt(Math.random() * letters.length));
  }
  return result;
}

function addSquare() {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  var squareArea = document.getElementById("squareArea");
  square.className = "square";
  square.style.left = parseInt(Math.random() * 650) + "px";
  square.style.top = parseInt(Math.random() * 250) + "px";
  square.style.width = "100px";
  square.style.height = "100px";
  square.style.position = "absolute";
  square.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  square.onclick = squareClick;
  squareArea.appendChild(square);
}

function changeColors() {
  var squares = document.querySelectorAll("#squareArea div");
  for (i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  }
}

function squareClick() {
  var oldZ = parseInt(this.style.zIndex);
  if (oldZ == maxZ) {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  } else {
    maxZ++;
    this.style.zIndex = maxZ;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Colored Squares</title>
  <script src="Squares.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="Squares.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="squareArea"></div>
  <div>
    <button id="add">Add Square</button>
    <button id="colors">Change Color</button>
  </div>
  <p>Click a square to move it to the front.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How would I get them to be able to be dragged?

Comment: You'll need to write the code for that. That's your assignment, not ours. We're here to help you, not do it for you.